# Bash script takes wrong conditional path for unknown reason

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have the following bash script that should list the folders in the same directory, and let me choose a folder to move in, and then list its content.

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3="Scelta?"

select dest in $( command ls -aF | grep "/" ); do
  if [ -d $dest ]; then
    cd $dest
    echo "$0 : changed to $dest"
    ls
    break

  else
    echo "$0 : wrong choice" 1>$2
  fi
done
```

the path of the script is something like

> /Users/myName/Documents/GitHub/SO/Exercise4

and this is the content of the Exercise4 dir

> 1/ 2/ 3/ 4/ 5/ select.sh

when I run the script it prompts me something like

```
1) ./
2) ../
3) 1/
4) 2/
5) 3/
6) 4/
7) 5/
Scelta?
```

If I choose an option between 1 and 7 the script works, but when I input a number out of that range, instead of echoing me "wrong choice" it lists me my home directory and I can't figure out why

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: (And in the future, consider running code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking about it here).

Comment: BTW, a better way to write this might be `select dest in */; do`. That'll work even if the names have spaces (or with a directory created with `mkdir '*'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why This Happens

Consider:

```
dest=
[ -d $dest ]
```

What does this do? It runs the command:

```
[ -d ]
```

What does *that* do? It's shorthand for:

```
[ -n "-d" ]
```

...which is to say, it checks whether `-d` is empty, which it isn't, so the result is true.

---

#### How To Stop It

1. **Use More Quotes**

   Consider this instead:

   ```
   dest=""
   [ -d "$dest" ]
   ```

   When run, it *doesn't* invoke `[ -d ]`; instead, it runs `[ -d '' ]`: *The quotes prevented the expansion results from being split into a different number of strings than they started as*.
2. **When On Bash, Consider The Extended Test Form**

   ```
   [[ -d $dest ]]
   ```

   ...suppresses string-splitting and glob expansion, so it works even without quotes.

Comment: This fixed it, but can you tell my why it listed the home directory with an input out of range?

Comment: `cd $dest`, with an empty `dest`, just runs `cd` -- and the default thing for `cd` to do is to switch to your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible it has something to do with the fact that you're using Classic Test

```
[ vs [[

if [[ -d $dest ]]; then
```

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression#behaviour_differences_compared_to_the_builtin_test_command

Or, you might just have to put quotations around it to evaluate correctly. It might just be that 8 is true and only 0 is false:

```
if [ -d "$dest" ]; then
```

I find the latter more likely; I make it a policy to quote absolutely everything all the time in bash, it's good practice.

Comment: Both of the things you speculate are true. Using `[[ ]]` will fix it; quoting correctly will *also* fix it. So this isn't an either-or.

Comment: That said, these items being offered in speculative rather than authoritative form is unfortunate. If you need to do your research to verify whether something is correct, the time to do that is *before* including content in an answer.